# Можно ли так говорить: "Документы ложАтся на стол директора"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Насколько верно использование выражения?

Comment: А чем вызвано сомнение?

Comment: -Бог мой! А кто же учит нынешних журналистов культуре речи?!!!
  "Эти документы ложатся на стол и губернатора, и министра сельского хозяйства Алтайского края"......Чёрт побери! Нет  такого слова в русском языке - "ложатся" - НЕТ! КЛАДУТСЯ!!! Грубейшая речевая ошибка!  - вот так выступила филолог по поводу одной газетной публикации) Я не сомневаюсь в правомерности употребления данного выражения, но аргументированно доказать ей  ничего не удается, так как я не филолог. Прошу компетентной помощи.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

"Документы ложатся на стол директора". Это образное выражение, в котором документы выступают как активная сила. Помните: "Листья жёлтые над городом кружатся, с тихим шорохом нам под ноги ложатся"?

В русском языке такое слово есть.

По-моему, писать "КЛАДУТСЯ" без указания, кем кладутся, — плохой стиль. Тогда уж лучше перейти в активный (действительный) залог: "Эти документы кладут на стол министру".

Comment: Привели этот аргумент! Последовала вот такая речь:исходить нужно из контекста...но Документы кладутся на стол, но не лОжатся, ни ложАтся - это страдательный залог несовершенного вида..то есть документы кем-то кладутся...
В вашем примере: "Листья жёлтые нам  под ноги ложАтся" - это действительный залог ..хотя и несовершенного вида...то есть листья сами ложАтся, как и медведи...

Comment: В советское время был такой пример данного казуса : "Снег ложится на землю, а партбилет кладётся на стол".  То есть нужно учитывать форму залога: действительный или страдательный...В предложении "Документы .... - залог страдательный...документы кем-то кладутся, но не сами...ПОЭТОМУ "Документы КЛАДУТСЯ...."- даже не знаю, что на это ответить)

Comment: Я бы спросил у журналиста, ее газета сама выходит или ее выводят.

Comment: Галина, если вы наберёте гуглом "легла бумага", то найдёте не один десяток книг с таким текстом, это вполне обычно; "ложилась" лишь объединяет несколько таких же случаев. А выражение "бумага прилегала" (к поверхности чего-нибудь) вы даже не сможете перевести в страдательный залог, не изменив смысла (приложить её можно, но на время прикладывания).

Comment: Зависит от стиля. В газетной статье я бы написал: "Партия разваливается. Партбилеты сотнями ложатся на столы парторгов".

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Попробую переубедить оппонента) Я-то как раз таки уверена, что это образное выражение имеет право на жизнь)

Comment: *это страдательный залог*  - поезд давно ушел, но я бы напомнил филологу (!), что действительного залога у возвратных глаголов не бывает. Хотя если смотреть в корень, то в чем-то она права.

Answer (score 3):

Кладутся обычно куры... Ну да ладно, вашему филологу виднее!

Я же думаю, что документы всё-таки *ложатся* на стол. В словаре Ефремовой, например, у этого глагола такое первое значение: «Принимать лежачее положение» — это совершенно подходит к нашей ситуации. И, что еще важно, глагол этот нейтральностилистический, в отличие от скорее разговорного *класться*.

Сама же журналистская фраза мне не нравится, можно было бы и менее канцелярски-топорно написать. Но нормативность глагола *ложиться* это не отменяет.

Справедливо замечание М_Г: если бы предложение было в действительном залоге, то есть без всяких *-ся* на конце глаголов, то употребление слова *ложить* (вместо литературного *класть*) было бы речевой ошибкой. В страдательном залоге, как в вашем примере, частичка *-ся* снимает с бедного *ложить* все непонятные обвинения и делает его вполне нормативным.

Comment: Спасибо за доступное пояснение)

Answer (score 2):

**Документы ложатся на стол директора.**

Использование слова **ложатся** в данном случае грамотно и уместно. Поиск в Google находит сотни примеров подобного использования в самых авторитетных изданиях: "книги ложатся на полки магазинов", "письма ложатся на стол редактора" и т. д. и т. п.

Вот пример предложения из журнала "Наука и жизнь", изд-во "Правда", 1970 г.:

> На стол следствия ложатся документы о Распутине.

Comment: Благодарю за убедительные примеры)

Answer (score 0):

Столько всего понаписали...
А суть-то не в этом.
***"Ложатся на стол"*** - вполне корректная фраза, но у неё смысл такой, что либо: a) действующее лицо (тот, кто "ложит") неизввестно или несущественно. 
Или как несколько фантастический вариант: в) ложатся в значении "помещаются", "укладываются", "подходят по размерам". *Cp: "Книга огромная по формату, но в ящик стола ложится".*

В остальных случаях лучше универсальное ***"документы кладутся"***.

//===

Интересно, что бы сказал редактор в ситуации, если бы обиженный автор распотрошил редакционную бухгалтерию, и устроил небольшой праздничный фейрферк из документов... Летают, типа, документы по кабинету, кружатся - и на стол редактора ложатся, ложатся...

Comment: О-о-о, вопросы две тысячи восемнадцатого года пошли...